# How can I run a shell script from python that calls another script?

Tags: python, shell, loops

Here's an example of the shell script:

```
python command_name.py --shell positional_arg1 positional_arg2 --option optional_arg1 --True_flag
```

I just want to be able to call this from a python script so I can loop through the script, changing different parameters through each loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["python", "--shell", "positional_arg1", "positional_arg2", 
                      "--option", "optional_arg1", "--True_flag"], shell=True, 
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = p.communicate()
```